# How many times the query will hit the database?

Tags: linq

Can any one plz optimize the below linq query.It should hit the database only once.

```
List<LearningItem> items = this.learningitemRepository.GetAll().ToList();

var model = new List<StatementViewerModel>();
foreach (var statement in subjects)
{
    var mi = new StatementViewerModel();
    mi.UserName = statement.UserName;
    mi.SubjectName = statement.Name;
    **int nofItems = items.Where(x => x.SubjectId == statement.SubjectId).Count();**
    double ratio = (double)statement.AttendedItems / (double)nofItems;
    int subjectprogress = (int)(ratio * 100);
    mi.Progress = subjectprogress;
    model.Add(mi);
}
```

Comment: Where's the problem?  Surely this only hits the DB once in its current state?

Comment: Thanks For the comments.I have the doubt,that's y posted the question.

Comment: If you doubt it, then turn on the profiler on your database and see what gets sent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have posted, your Database should only be being accessed through the `GetAll()` method of your `learmingitemRepository`.  So if you are worried that you are querying the Database more than once, the `GetAll()` function is where you should look (assuming your example is not in a function that is being repeatedly called itself).

The rest of your code is iterating over your `subjects` collection and adding objects to your `model` collection.  There does not appear to be anything in the `foreach` loop that is accessing your Database.